# Web Scraping on login sites with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

New to web scraping, am trying to login to Wikipedia using Python as a start.

Cant seem to do it. Here’s my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

LOGINURL = ‘https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=Main+Page’

REQUESTURL = ‘ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Notifications’

session = requests.Session()
soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(LOGINURL).text,’html.parser’)

token = soup.find(“input”,{“name”:”wpLoginToken})[“value”]

details = {‘wpName1’:input(‘input username’), ‘wpPassword1’:input(‘input pw’),’wpLoginToken’:token}

post = session.post(LOGINURL,data=details)

r=session.get(REQUESTURL).text
print(r)
```

when i print r, it is still the login page

Answer (score 1):

You can use `selenium` instead of `requests` in order to login to websites. This is how you do it:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=Main+Page')

uname = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wpName1"]')

uname.click()

uname.send_keys('Username')

pswrd = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wpPassword1"]')

pswrd.click()

pswrd.send_keys('Password')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wpLoginAttempt"]').click()
```

Comment: I’ve pip install selenium, cant seem to run the code. Is there other downloads I have to do?

Comment: Yeah. You have to install chromedriver and place it in the same directory as ur python script. You can download it from here according to ur chrome version: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: I have an error of “Failed to load extension from: ((my path)). Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator”.

Comment: Currently on a company laptop. Does this mean i can’t use selenium?

Comment: Oh...Aren't you allowed to download anything on your company laptop?

Comment: I can. Downloaded the chromedriver and ran the code. Got that error. Are there other ways to do this, other than selenium?

Comment: You just have to place the ```chromedriver.exe``` file in the same directory. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should work. I could not test it as I don't have account in there.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

LOGINURL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=Main+Page"
REQUESTURL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Notifications'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(LOGINURL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
    payload = {i['name']: i.get('value', '') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload['wpName'] = 'yourusername'  #------------------->change it accordingly
    payload['wpPassword'] = 'yourpassword'  #------------------->change it accordingly
    payload['title'] = 'Special:UserLogin'
    payload['wploginattempt'] = 'Log in'
    payload.pop('fulltext')
    payload.pop('search')
    payload.pop('go')
    s.post(LOGINURL,data=payload)
    r = s.get(REQUESTURL).text
    print(r)
```